# Complex wave creation

Tags: waves

I'm wondering about the creation of complex waves. For example if I had an infinitely long piece of rope and a mechanism to add energy to it in constantly varying ways so it became an incredibly long and complex wave. Do physicists regard all variances as different waves (breaking the energies down into smaller measurements) or would the entirety be regarded as a "complex wave" (a single unit)?

Note: I came to think of this after reading about neutrino oscillations and also thought that waves created in the early universe that have yet to interact with anything could be very detailed. Also a wave-function is said to include all possibilities for movement.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "regard all variances as different waves (breaking the energies down into smaller measurements) or would the entirety be regarded as a "complex wave" (a single unit)"

Comment: @garyp - For example if I move the rope up and down by one meter per millisecond for 20 seconds horizontally and then change for 25 seconds to 0.5 meters per second vertically (and so on without repeating a pattern) I would call that a variance but because its caused by the same mechanism without a break is it not the same wave? (or do physicists call each new pattern a new wave?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re.

> Do physicists regard all variances as different waves (breaking the
>   energies down into smaller measurements) or would the entirety be
>   regarded as a "complex wave" (a single unit)?

Either approach could be used depending on the situation.  Many times breaking the wave into simpler wave components is preferred.

For a simple example: if the wave is given by $f(x-ct)+g(x-ct)$ and if the system is linear, each wave, $f(x-ct)$ and $g(x-ct)$ can be considered separately.  This does not have to done in the frequency domain (Fourier analysis) but instead can be done in the time-space domain without considering each frequency component separately.  This can be useful for non periodic waves and especially short non repeating pulses.

Comment: thank you - and what would be the upper limit definition of a "*short pulse*" - 1000th of a second?

Comment: Depends on the physical situation you are considering--could be 1 ms, 1sec, 1day ...

Answer (score 1):

A complicated waveform is not a "single unit"; it can in principle be mathematically "taken apart" or separated out into a list of different individual fundamental frequencies whose sum yields back the original complex waveform. The mathematical tool used to decompose complicated signals or waveforms into their constituent frequencies is called *Fourier analysis*.

Comment: I see, a bit like ephemerides